# How does global variables work on imported functions?

Tags: python, global, argparse

I have multiple scripts that needs to be wrapped by a master script. Each script has functions that include input argument, used within that script.

For example, foo.py:

```
import argparse
import sys
import os 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("foo_input_dir")
parser.add_argument("foo_ouput_dir")
args = parser.parse_args()

def foo(input_file):
    print input_file
    print args.foo_input_dir
    print args.foo_ouput_dir
```

and the master script is supposed to get input of the directory with the files and the list of files, bar.py:

```
import argparse
import foo

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("main_input")
parser.add_argument("input_dir")
parser.add_argument("ouptut_dir")
args = parser.parse_args()

def bar():  
    print args
    foo.foo(main_input)

bar()
```

However, when I try to run this in command line, I get following errors:

With 3 arguments, as needed by bar.py

> python bar.py sample /usr/ /bin/
>
> > usage: bar.py [-h] foo_input_dir foo_ouput_dir
> >
> > bar.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /bin/

With 2 arguments,

> python bar.py /usr/ /bin/
>
> > usage: bar.py [-h] main_input input_dir ouptut_dir
> >
> > bar.py: error: too few arguments

I am trying to make `foo()` to use the input given to `bar.py` as `args.foo_input_dir` and `args.foo_output_dir`.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the arguments in both files?

Comment: @kindall I updated the question with an example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to merge multiple scripts into one script that calls those scripts. Those scripts were written in a way that each scripts would get command line arguments.

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? It's not currently clear why you'd want to jam two separate command line scripts together or what the best approach might be.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with global variables.  What's happening is that both parsers are run on the command line `sys.argv`.

When you run `bar.py` it imports `foo`.  As part of that import it creates the parser and does the `parse_args`, expecting 2 strings.  If it gets 3, it raise the error and quits.

But now `main` creates its own parser and runs that.  It expects 3 strings, and objects if it only sees the 2 that `foo` accepted.

The key is that both parsers use the same `sys.argv`.

The `usage` line in the two errors makes it clear which parser is objecting.

In general it is not a good idea to run two independent parsers in the same code.  You can make it work, but it takes a lot more coordination than it's worth. There have been several SO questions when people try add their own arguments to an API defined by an import package such as the Google youtube API.

Usually we put the parser for an importable module in a `if __name__` block (or at least it's `parser.parse_args` call).  That way it is only used when used as a script.  It is not used when imported.

---

These two files work together

foo.py:

```
import argparse

def make_parser():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("foo_input_dir")
   parser.add_argument("foo_ouput_dir")
   return parser

def foo(input_file):
    print input_file
    print 'foo', args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = make_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    foo('test')
```

bar.py

```
import argparse
import foo

def bar():
    print 'bar', args
    foo.foo(args.main_input)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("main_input")
parser.add_argument("input_dir")
parser.add_argument("ouptut_dir")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    foo.args = args  # make args visible to foo.foo
    bar()

1827:~/mypy/stack41947308$ python foo.py a b
test
foo Namespace(foo_input_dir='a', foo_ouput_dir='b')
1828:~/mypy/stack41947308$ python bar.py a b c
bar Namespace(input_dir='b', main_input='a', ouptut_dir='c')
a
foo Namespace(input_dir='b', main_input='a', ouptut_dir='c')
```

Making the `bar.args` variable visible in `foo` requires a special step.
 And the attribute names are different.

As a general rule it isn't a good idea to use global variables in a function that might be imported.  It's fine to use globals that are guaranteed to be defined in its own module (module constants), but don't depend on ones that will be set by the importer.  It's safer to pass all variables as arguments.